# How to move selected item to div?

Tags: php

I'm newbie of php and sorry for this question but how can i move (using PHP) a selected item to div?

```
<div id="btn"></div>
<ul>
    <li class="selected">Alfa</li>
    <li>Beta</li>
    <li>Gamma</li>
    <li>Delta</li>
    <li>Epsilon</li>
    <li>Zeta</li>
</ul>
```

I want to move the **li.selected** to the **div#btn**. I tried with `echo "<li class=selected></li>";` but doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: `<li>` cannot be a child element of `<div>`. It must be inside the `<ul>`. But your question needs to be fleshed out more. PHP cannot modify what is rendered by the browser after the fact, that is JavaScript's job. What are you using PHP for? Is this HTML markup in a string in PHP?

Comment: it does not matter.. just show him how to do it! I am guessing you need to use jQuery instead of PHP

Comment: PHP runs on the server-side. I think what are are trying to do requires JavaScript

Comment: do you mean the content of <li> in to <div>? hmm... maybe via jQuery:text?? http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: @shnisaka What do you mean it doesn't matter? Of course it matters. This question cannot reasonably be answered unless we understand what the OP is trying to accomplish, and in what context. This could be HTML markup retrieved into a string, it could be already rendered.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski you can still do it even if it is not HTML validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is server side language and for moving item to div you should send request to server and build "new" page.

For your example you should add form to your page and change li to input with type radio or checkbox.

But I think for your example you not need PHP - you can make this in Javascript.

Comment: Thank you, Ok! I will use javascript.

Answer (score 2):

PHP runs on the server side. What you are trying to do requires JavaScript. 
Using following jQuery code, you can do the following:

```
   //Iterate through each <li> element having the class "selected"
    $("li.selected").each(function() { 
       //For each of these, append the text within the <li> element into the div with id "btn" (wrapped within a span- can change as needed)
       $('#btn').append('<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>');
    });
```

To import jQuery on your page, you can use:

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript to do that, using jQuery it will be smething like

```
$('div#btn').text($('li.selected').text());
```

if you want to change that on change selected on click then

```
$('li.selected').click(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    self.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $('div#btn').text(self.text());
});
```